# Battery won't charge beyond 53%

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenovo B560 windows 7. I recently purchased a new battery but it won't charge beyond 53%. I tried some suggestions like uninstalling Microsoft ACPI-Complaint Control Method(which didn't uninstall or work at all), then battery gauge reset using the energy management but it still didn't solve the problem. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try calibrating the battery, see full instructions here:

[Calibrating the Notebook Battery](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?tmp_forceView=desktop&cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c00817650&lang=en&lc=en&product=3807969&query=Dv5-1125em&tmp_task=solveCategory&tool=)

There's step by step instructions, but in short what you need to is:

Allow the battery to charge to it's maximum capacity, whatever that might be, disconnect the power cord from the computer, create a new power plan that will allow the battery to discharge completely until the computer shuts down. The battery level reading on the power meter should now be accurate.

Note however, when you complete the calibration, and the battery reading shows 100% when charged, my advice is to check how long the battery holds when fully charged, and compare that to your old battery. Even if you calibrate the battery correctly, there's a chance the reading in your case showed 53% when full is because the battery has other problems, like lower capacity. Do this as soon as possible so you could return the battery if there are problems.